# Can't load file /../firebase.js ... . Encoding is not UTF-8

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Describe your environment:
Operating System version: mac os
Firebase SDK version: 4.8.1
Firebase Product: database

Describe the problem:
browser show error When I try add firebase.js to chrome extension:
Can't load file /../firebase.js ... . Encoding is not UTF-8.
I try convert it to utf-8 but browser show error anyway

Steps to reproduce:
download firebase.js using https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.8.1/firebase.js
add firebase.js to chrome extension package
enable developer mode in chrome browser
load extension to chrome browser

Comment: It is probably an issue due to Uglify like the one described here: https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/5798

Comment: Any progress here? Sadly, I am in the same situation

Comment: I did a search for `/\uffff/` as one of the answers below suggests. It returns two results, each of them are shortly followed by an non utf-8 character (represented by a `◻` in my code editor and `<ffff>` in vi). If you replace these characters with an empty string, then the file becomes utf-8 compliant and can be used (although I am not 100% sure to what detriment).

Answer (score 2):

search Ib=/\uffff/.test

then you will find the error cause

Comment: in firebase.js, search /\uffff/.test

Comment: Thank you, it was your reply that solved for me. Just searched and removed that. How we can replace this with?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest checking the official [Firebase Chrome extension sample](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-chrome-extension) in github along with the [Power your Chrome Extension with Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/03/power-your-chrome-extension-with.html)

And this may be the part of the manifest.json you're looking for:

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://cdn.firebase.com https://*.firebaseio.com https://*.firebaseio-demo.com; object-src 'self'",
```

This should get started you with adding Firebase to your Chrome extensions.

Additional sample: [Firebase Auth w/ Google Sign-In in Chrome Extensions](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/tree/master/auth/chromextension)

Comment: Hello. Thank you. In samples I see that firebase use only background.htm (or background.js) . But I don't understand how use firebase sdk in content scripts :(  Found only  solution with using chrome.runtime.sendMessage and so on .

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you can look into importing only the necessary Firebase services' scripts your app needs ([doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup)). For example, you can import `https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.12.0/firebase-app.js` (required) and `https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.12.0/firebase-database.js` (for the realtime database). These two give no UTF-8 encoding error. However, `firebase-auth.js` (for the authentication service) will cause the same error, unfortunately.

A better solution would be to fix the encoding issue which is likely due to the minification process ([similar issue](https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/5798)).